# Plugging in laptop to charger increases ping and reduces download speeds

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, internet, ping

HP Pavilion dv6z-7000 CTO

I just can't wrap my head around this one.

My brother is playing League of Legends, has 99 ping. I plug in my laptop, his ping immediately spikes to 1k then eventually hovers between 200-300ms.

At the same time, my download speed drops from 1.50 MBps to 40KBps.

Everything goes back to normal after I unplug it.

Comment: "plug in" … to what? If you mean to the mains power, then this becomes a bizarre coincidence - https://superuser.com/questions/1484255/why-is-my-ping-higher-when-my-charger-is-plugged-into-my-dell-precision-m6800-la - or perhaps something Windows just did in a recent update.

Comment: To laptop charger -_-

Comment: I added more, see revised comment. Did you just get a Windows update?

Comment: Both computers are wireless I presume. Is the charger you’re using the original charger that came with the laptop new? This sounds like wireless interference. This is something a Chinese knock off power adapter might do.

Comment: No i both it additional
Not original..

Comment: Maybe your laptop charger causes electromagnetic radiation that disturbs your wireless? Because it is a cheap, unshielded clone? Then I'd also be afraid that it may not even be safe to use...

Comment: @anony-mousse I'm calling b.s... even an unshielded clone charger/adapter would not cause this type of interference. It would have to be giving off electro-magnetic radiation in the 2.4ghz or 5ghz range which is pretty much impossible. The circuits used for voltage step down from mains power are in the 20khz to 50khz range. (Designed to be outside of human hearing range) so you don't hear an audible whine coming from the adapter. If you crack open the next adapter that fails on you, you will find that 99% oem or not **are not shielded**

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Us old amateur radio folks know that intermediate frequencies can also cause problems, as well as other frequencies not directly sitting in 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz bands.

Comment: @K7AAY, Please cite some references, I'm not new to radio. The only thing I'm aware of that could cause any interference from a **switched mode power supply** would be an unintended harmonic frequency. I've never seen a harmonic frequency that was in the order of billions of CPS higher than the original signal that created it. (Which would be required in this case) Not trying to be a jerk, but if you could kindly point me to any RF formula that describes behavior even close to this, I will retract my comment.

Comment: @Captain Awesome May I please ask what happens, for testing purposes, if you connect to your router with an Ethernet Cable instead? Please click [edit] and add that useful info to the original question; please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].

Comment: @Tim Stewart https://www.google.com/search?q=EMI+%22difference+frequency%22

Comment: @K7AAY, did you have something specific to cite? I'm not sifting through 12 hours of technical papers that literally have nothing to do with what we are discussing. Forgive me for not taking your word for it, but the last time I saw you post something regarding frequency, it was blatantly wrong... https://superuser.com/posts/1342009/edit/fc498ec6-3675-4b57-82b1-1f09f23d66e6

Answer (score 4):

Try creating a custom power plan, go for all performance while plugged in.

In device manager, under your wireless card check to see if you have power management options. If you do turn them off. Check to see if you can replicate the problem.

This is probably caused by the non-oem charger.
If it's voltage/amperage are not up to spec for the design of the computer, it could be confusing the power management drivers.

If either of these work to stop this issue, get a oem charger for the laptop.

Answer (score 2):

If it is signal interference look for the signal to noise ratio under the wireless settings. If the number of decibels changes when it's plugged in interference is the likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

this is a power problem. The charger cannot supply the watts necessary to run the motherboard/CPU at full speed so it drops to lowest possible speed. The laptop probably charges the battery really really slowly as well. You need a new charger. And you can also change the setting in BIOS to alert you to a low functioning charger. But you will need a new power brick/cable.

Answer (score -1):

Open a support ticket with HP. This is an issue with certain versions of Windows but the only way to put pressure on Microsoft is through a well respected partner, like HP. Plus, it looks like a hardware issue so HP will be motivated to blame Microsoft. The more tickets they receive about this issue the faster it will get resolved.